# Why is my flag not working on maximum trigger depth exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, loop, insert

I have written a trigger for purchases if the purchase contains several of the same purchase detail items they should be summed up and merged as 1 purchase detail. When I use a before insert I get in a loop because the inserts are checked again. I used a flag to stop this but this doesn't work. What am I missing?

Trigger

```
trigger AankoopDetailTrigger on Aankoop_Detail__c (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore) {
        // Process before insert
        if( Trigger.isInsert){
            AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.isBeforeInsert(trigger.new);
            if(AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.aankRecursion)
                return;
            AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.aankRecursion = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Triggerhandler

```
public class AankoopDetailTriggerHandler {
    public static boolean aankRecursion;
    static {
        aankRecursion = false;
    }
    //before insert
    public static void isBeforeInsert(List<Aankoop_Detail__c> aankoopdetailList){
        Map<String, Decimal> amounts = new Map<String, Decimal>();
        for (Aankoop_Detail__c purchase : aankoopdetailList)
        {
            if (!amounts.containsKey(purchase.Aankoop__c ))
                amounts.put(purchase.Aankoop__c , purchase.Prijs__c );
            else
                amounts.put(purchase.Aankoop__c , amounts.get(purchase.Aankoop__c ) + purchase.Prijs__c );
        }
        List<Aankoop_Detail__c> records = new List<Aankoop_Detail__c>();
        for (String name : amounts.keySet())
            records.add(new Aankoop_Detail__c(Aankoop__c=name, Prijs__c =amounts.get(name)));
        insert records;
    }
}
```

Test

```
@isTest
public class AankoopDetailTriggerHandlerTest{

    @testSetup
    public static void test_Data(){
        Winkel__c shop = new Winkel__c(name='name' , Store_Id__c  = 007 , Winkelnaam__c = 'Shopname');
        insert shop;
        Aankoop__c buy = new Aankoop__c(name='buy' , Winkel__c  = shop.id);
        insert buy;
        Aankoop_Detail__c  buydet1 = new Aankoop_Detail__c(name = 'det-001' , Aankoop__c = buy.id);
        insert buydet1;
        Aankoop_Detail__c  buydet2  = new Aankoop_Detail__c(name = 'det-001' , Aankoop__c = buy.id);
        insert buydet2;
    }
    @isTest
    public static void test_Method_1(){
        system.assertEquals(1,[SELECT id FROM Aankoop_Detail__c].size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a general comment, static boolean recursion guards like yours will break if/when you try to insert more than 200 records. Generally speaking, the next logical progression would be to use a `static Set<Id>` (to track individual Ids that you've processed already). That's a bit difficult in a `before insert` trigger, however, as your records won't yet have an Id at that point. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're seeing recursion because your recursion guard is in the wrong place. When this gets executed:

```
        AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.isBeforeInsert(trigger.new);
        if(AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.aankRecursion)
            return;
        AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.aankRecursion = true;
```

what happens is something like this:

- Insert goes off
- `before insert` trigger executed
- `isBeforeInsert` called.
- `insert` DML occurs inside `isBeforeInsert`.
- `before insert` trigger executed.
- `isBeforeInsert` called.
- `insert` DML occurs inside `isBeforeInsert`.

and so on until the limit goes off. Your recursion-guard Boolean is never set and never checked, because you don't touch it until *after* the recursion takes place - meaning it never actually executes.

The direct fix to this is placing the trigger handler invocation last:

```
        if(AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.aankRecursion)
            return;
        AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.aankRecursion = true;
        AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.isBeforeInsert(trigger.new);
```

That fixes the recursion issue, but it doesn't result in the trigger doing what you want. Your unit test case:

```
@isTest
public static void test_Method_1(){
    system.assertEquals(1,[SELECT id FROM Aankoop_Detail__c].size());
}
```

is still going to fail: that `SELECT` will return 3, because you've got the two records you inserted in your `@testSetup` method, plus another that you inserted in your trigger handler. Your handler doesn't do anything to impede those records from being inserted in the first place.

Additionally, your test class isn't populating the `Prijs__c` field, so you'll have a problem when you try to do your arithmetic.

There isn't a good way to transform data that's being inserted like this inside the trigger itself. I would recommend firing a Queueable from the trigger to handle this cleanup in a separate transaction by inserting the new records and *deleting* the original duplicates, which seems to be what you want to do.

Otherwise, you'd need to `addError()` on the original duplicate records, but that will result in an exception and a rollback of the transaction in most cases. (Unless the error's caught and handled elsewhere in the call stack, or the caller used `Database.insert(myList, false)` to allow partial success. That's the only way for your trigger to impede the insert of the duplicates like this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check *before* calling the rest of your handler:

```
if(AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.aankRecursion)
    return;
AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.aankRecursion = true;
AankoopDetailTriggerHandler.isBeforeInsert(trigger.new);
```